# When will Europe allow phones (to communicate) on planes?

Tags: commercial-aviation, easa-regulations, cell-phone

Currently USA has allowed phones to be used in commercial flights, is there a similar ruling coming to Europe or will my mid air Bluetooth battles have to wait?

Comment: AFAIK, there has already been talks made by 1/2 big operators to allow phone and should be in by the end of 2015

Comment: What do you mean by "to communicate"? If this is using the wi-fi or bluetooth, you can as long as the aircraft is equipped with wi-fi or as long as you operate your own wi-fi access point. To use cellular connection you need the aircraft to be equipped and the airliner to have a aggrement with a cell phone company. The cellular network is not designed to connect phones that are at high height (more than few tenth of meters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar ruling since last week.

The use of electronic equipment as long as they are in "flight mode" during all phases of flight was already allowed in Europe by EASA since [November 2013](https://www.easa.europa.eu/newsroom-and-events/press-releases/easa-allows-use-electronic-devices-board).

Since last week ([26 November 2014](https://www.easa.europa.eu/newsroom-and-events/press-releases/easa-allows-electronic-devices-remain-and-connected-throughout)) EASA also allows phones to be on and connected throughout the flight. This allows for WiFi services, phone services and Bluetooth battles during the flight.

Before allowing the use of these electronics in flight, airlines have to assess the impact of the signals transmitted by the mobile devices on the aircraft, ensuring aircraft systems are not affected. For this reason mobile communication will not be allowed by all airlines on all flights at once.